# What is auto _ in a lambda function's parameters?

Tags: c++, lambda

In [link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/ReduceOps.cpp#L1135-L1136) we see `auto _` in the lambda function's parameter list. I am wondering what is `_`?

Comment: `int _ = 1; printf("%d\n", _);` is the same as `int a = 1; printf("%d\n", a);`

Comment: In C++, `_` is just a single character identifier.  Some languages (not C++) use `_` to signify an ignored parameter (C++ has `std::ignore` for that).  Some C++ devs might use `_` as an ignored parameter, but that'd just be their own convention.

Answer (score 3):

`_` is an identifier. You could view it like `x` or `arg` or any other identifier, but apparently this programmer chose to use `_`, perhaps in order to avoid choosing a name that might have any semantic significance.

Comment: In C++, _ is simply an ordinary variable name. The Rust language uses _ to designate an unnamed variable that is never directly referred to, so it is a special symbol in Rust. But this is C++, so it's nothing special.